# Can't get working two or more links in the same Android layout

Tags: android, textview

My problem is that I can't open two identically defined links in the same layout, just the first one. If I long-click the first one, a context menu appears saying "Copy URL", but for the second one, it doesn't. The links are valid ones.

Here are the two textviews defined:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_id1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="@string/text1"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_id2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="@string/text2"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

I'm running a custom rom with Android 2.3.7 (CyanogenMod) on a Motorola Defy (Jordan). I tried it on the emulator, but it doesn't work either.

Any answers are well appreciated.

---

EDIT:

```
<string name="text1"><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a></string>
<string name="text2"><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">Text2</a></string>
```

Comment: What's the actual text of text1 and text2?

Comment: just check your "android:text="@string/text2" and "android:text="@string/text2";
also check "android:id="@+id/txt_id2" and "android:id="@+id/txt_id1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess what. If I do something like this:
    `<string name="text1"><a href="http://www.google.com">Text1</a></string>`
it is underlined, highlighted, etc. as a link, but it doesn't redirect me to the desired page.

Instead, if I insert in the textview this string `android:text="http://www.google.com"` it is also underlined and highlighted as a link, but this time it redirects me to the desired page.

This means I don't need any `<a>`s.